# Javascript Date showing Wrong TimeZone "GMT+0521 (India Standard Time)"

Tags: javascript, date

I am having simple question.

> **Why JavaScript show's wrong TimeZone if the date is after the year 1906**
>
> Please find the below screenshot for the same.

---

[image: Chrome Console]

Comment: i dont have this issue.

Comment: have you tried the same date "01-01-1905" ?

Comment: yes, the same date

Comment: Seems fine here,.  One thing I will point out though, `01-01-1905` is not a valid date constructor.  You could try -> `1905-01-01` see if that helps..

Comment: I think it's because of the difference of GMT and UTC

Comment: I tried now with Chrome Console  
new Date("1905-01-01")
-- output Sun Jan 01 1905 05:21:10 GMT+0521 (India Standard Time)
new Date("1906-01-01")
-- output Mon Jan 01 1906 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: Chrome is behaving differently and IE is behaving differently. IE is showing 5:30 and chrome same 5:21

Comment: @Keith—it’s not a format supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent. It may return a valid Date or not.

Comment: @RobG  Yes, that was kind of my point.

Comment: @Keith—the format YYYY-MM-DD will be parsed as UTC whereas just about everything else will be parsed as local so not really a good alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India

> Though British India did not officially adopt the standard time zones
>   until 1905, when the meridian passing east of Allahabad at 82.5° E
>   longitude was picked as the central meridian for India, corresponding
>   to a single time zone for the country (UTC+5:30). Indian Standard Time
>   came into force on 1 January 1906, and also applied to Sri Lanka (then
>   Ceylon). However, Calcutta time was officially maintained as a
>   separate time zone until 1948 and Bombay time until 1955.[8]

and

> Some older time zones were:
>
> Bombay Time (UTC+04:51), Madras Time (UTC+05:21) Calcutta Time
>   (UTC+05:54), Port Blair mean time

Comment: I am really amused by this. Thanks for such lovely info